# 2D graphics acceleration in SDL2 for Windows game development

Tags: windows, opengl, graphics, 2d, sdl-2

I am using Pascal and SDL2.0.5 for 2D game development for windows and as the development progresses it starts to show frame rate drop, especially as I am using each frame particles. I don't use graphics acceleration. I'm just using the SDL2 API. I want to ask you:

- For windows should I choose OpenGL or Direct3d?
- Will I see asignificant change in my games performance?

Comment: For the first point, the question is, do you have any experience with either API? Learning to properly use OpenGL or Direct 3D takes some serious work and is nothing you can get over with in a few weeks - at least from my viewpoint. For the second point, the answer is: it depends. Are you targeting specific hardware or is your goal to be able to run anywhere, even without hardware support (which can be achieved by shipping a software implementation of OpenGL, for instance). Why not use the Unreal Engine or Unity as a starting point?

Comment: 1. I don't have any previous experience with graphics acceleration, but I know C++ and Lazy Foo has EXTENDED tutorials on OpenGL with SDL2. I am not planning to do a sloppy work for some weeks, I intend to learn the thing inside-out for the months to come with Lazy-foo and many MANY video tutorials I have gathered. I just don't know what is optimal for Windows platform. OpenGL or Direct3d?.....2.I'm targeting Windows only, and I don't want to use a game engine because I HAVE to use Pascal for a diploma assignment.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't use graphics acceleration.

Are you sure? SDL2 uses hardware acceleration by default unless you create your renderer explicitly with `SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer`, or if you don't use `SDL_Renderer` in the first place.

> For windows should I choose OpenGL or Direct3d?

If you do use `SDL_Renderer`, make sure you're using `SDL_CreateRenderer`, and SDL will use what it thinks is best for the platform it's running on.

Otherwise, it doesn't really matter, especially for a 2D game. While on one system, one API might outperform the other, on another system the opposite might be true. When you look at the big picture, both average out to be roughly the same in terms of performance. Since you don't care about portability, pick the one that looks easiest to you.

> Will I see asignificant change in my games performance?

Yes. Hardware acceleration is faster in almost every case. The only exception that comes to mind is when you need to render frames pixel by pixel.